# Access output a multi line fild to a fix width

Tags: ms-access

I am using MS Access and have to create a file from a query, some of the fields are quite large and the program I am importing into only allows a max length of 65 characters. How do I insert line feed into those fields. The information is already in access so I cant do it by data validation on the fields.

Comment: How would inserting line feed help? String length still more than 65 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Left(LongLine, 65) & Chr(13) + Chr(10) & Right(LongLine, Len(LongLine) - 65) As _Line
FROM YourTable
```